# What does "baptism now saves you" mean in 1 Peter 3:21

Tags: word-study, authorial-intent, colossians, soteriology, baptism

What does **baptism now saves you** mean in

> [1 Peter 3:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?qs_version=NASB&quicksearch=baptism&begin=67&end=67) Corresponding to that, **baptism now saves** you—not the
>   removal of dirt from the flesh, but an appeal to God for a good
>   conscience—through the resurrection of Jesus Christ,

Does baptism here refer to immersion in water? Is this verse saying that immersion in water is the act that procures the repentant believer the new birth ( born again experience )?